# React, Enzyme: Testing a state update-Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm struggling to understand how to properly trigger a state update that can be verified.  Essentially I have 2 cases I'm trying to test which relate solely to the visual state of a button.

1) test that the button visually becomes selected
2) test that the button visually becomes disabled

The app

```
 export default function App() {
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

 return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Testing Style Update</h1>
    <Button
      className={`buttonBase ${selected && "buttonSelected"}`}
      clicked={() => setSelected(!selected)}
      selected={selected}
    />
  </div>
  );
}
```

the button

```
const Button = ({ className, selected, clicked }) => (
  <button className={className} onClick={clicked}>
    {selected
      ? "Click me to Remove the new style"
      : "Click me to add a new style"}
  </button>
);
export default Button;
```

the test

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import Enzyme, { mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Button from "./Button";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("App", () => {
  it("renders", () => {
    mount(<App />);
});

it("button visually becomes selected when clicked", () => {
const wrapper = mount(<App />);

const btn = wrapper.find(Button);
expect(btn).toBeDefined(); // <- passes
expect(btn.hasClass("buttonSelected")).toEqual(false); // <- passes

btn.simulate("click");
wrapper.update();
expect(btn.hasClass("buttonSelected")).toEqual(true);// <- fails
});
```

Visually, this works as expected.

What am I missing in regards to seeing the state properly update in the test?

My guess is that once I can figure this out, I'll be able to apply the same logic to the disabled side of things.

Thanks in advance

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/testingreactusestate-3bvv7

UPDATE:
Based on the first answer provided, I was able to get the test to pass within my sandbox, but not within my dev environment.

It's possible that Material-UI is causing some discrepancy, but I know the classname I'm looking for:

Here is the dev test

```
it("Updates it's classes when selected", () => {
  wrapper = mount(
       <ul>// required because the FilterListItem is an 'li' element
        <FilterListItem/>
      </ul>
  );

  let btn = wrapper.find(Button);
  expect(btn).toBeDefined(); // <- PASS
  // verify that the correct style is not present
  expect(btn.hasClass("makeStyles-selected-5")).toEqual(false);// <- PASS

  btn.simulate("click");

  // re-find the node
  btn = wrapper.find(Button);
  expect(btn).toBeDefined(); // <- PASS
  // check that the correct style has now been added
  expect(btn.hasClass("makeStyles-selected-5")).toEqual(true);//<-FAIL
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test makes sense correct, the only thing you missed is that with enzyme 3 you need to re-find your component after triggering an event because its properties will not be updated ([reference](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md#calling-props-after-a-state-change)).

As a further check, just log the wrapper before simulating the click event:

```
btn.simulate("click");
console.log(wrapper.find(Button).debug()); // re-find Button 
console.log(btn.debug()); // your code using btn
```

output will be

```
<Button className="buttonBase buttonSelected"...
<Button className="buttonBase false"...
```

So as you see the component has been correctly updated after the `click`. The issue is just re-finding the component you need to test.

BONUS: you don't need to `update()`

Comment: So in my trials to get this working, my original version had me expecting this:

expect( getComputedStyle(wrapper.find(Button).getDOMNode()).getPropertyValue(
          "background-color"
        )
      ).toBe("transparent");

Which worked fine, and was more in line with what I was trying to test.  But when i did that same thing to check if the background color changed, it still failed.

Isn't that essentially re-finding the component?

Comment: Note: I did the following:

 expect( getComputedStyle(wrapper.find(Button).getDOMNode()).getPropertyValue( "background-color" ) ).toBe("white");

right after the simulated click, just fyi

Comment: Updated my question with new material

Comment: Will you update the sandbox or show how this new "makeStyles-selected-5" class is set in the component? Also for debugging, have you tried `console.log(wrapper.debug())` after the simulating `click` event?

Comment: That class is generated from Material UI, but essentially, it gets added the exact same way. If state is true, its added, if false, its not.
I'll try to throw together a Material UI version in sandbox.  I left it out from the original post because I felt i could get state to update I'd be good to go.

Comment: And the output from the wrapper is extensive, but essentially `className="makeStyles-button-4 false"` that is what is on the button AFTER the click event. Obviously false should be `makeStyles-selected-5`

Comment: Update: I'm going to leave this as the accepted answer because I realize that the button in the production code is getting its state via a useEffect, not onclick, thanks for your help!